# How to move a file from sources directory to the resources directory with the same path in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources

Let's say there is a file named `baz.txt` that resides in a directory with the relative path `src/main/java/foo/bar`.

Is there a possibility in IntelliJ IDEA to move this file to the appropreate resources directory?

I.e. from

```
src/main/java/foo/bar/baz.txt
```

to

```
src/main/resources/foo/bar/baz.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the option to `Refactor` > `Move` the file (normally it's <kbd>F6</kbd>).

The popup will contain the current path of the file. Just replace `java` with `resources` in the path and click OK. IntelliJ will fix the folders and everything for you.